# How do I display random pages in Wordpress from a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a code snippet in my theme's function.php file that allows for a random page to display when you hit the URL www.mydomain.com/random. It looks like this:

```
add_action('init','random_post');
function random_post() {
       global $wp;
       $wp->add_query_var('random');
       add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
}

add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
function random_template() {
       if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
               $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
               foreach($posts as $post) {
                       $link = get_permalink($post);
               }
               wp_redirect($link,307);
               exit;
       }
}
```

But what I would like is for it to apply to only a single category of posts on my site. So something like www.mydomain.com/categories/mycategory/random

PHP isn't my thing, so I don't know what to tweak on this code to make that happen, or if it's even possible as written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random post in a specific URL then you can create a page called "Random" so your url will be www.domainname.com/random now create page template

```
<?php 
//Template Name: Template random
//add your random post generate code
$posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
               foreach($posts as $post) {
                       echo $link = get_permalink($post);
               }
?>
```

And just assign random page template to that new "Template random"

Comment: That's essentially what the code I've already got does. What I'm looking to do is limit the pool of possible random posts to a single category.

Comment: 4 years late to the party but you can pass a category ID to the get_posts() function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#parameters